# adding javascript events to freemind maps

Tags: javascript, freemind

I have created freemind maps using the tool, right now in the process of integrating the map with my web application.

I have some questions on the usage of freemind maps:

1. Instead of using the `freemindbrowser.html` and the jar file to integrate a map with a website/web app, can we do an export to Javascript from the tool and then integrate that exported file (.html) with the web site?
2. I want to be able to add javascript functions on events like node click, how do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to attach scripts written in Groovy for freemind version 0.9...
The new freemind described in http://sourceforge.net/projects/freemind/forums/forum/22102/topic/4990625 supplies the capability of attaching scripts to nodes in javascript.

Comment: Thanks, I will be trying this out